# ASP.NET:New Action doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have started a web api project and I am trying to add a new action to my existing controller. Here is my controller code and configurations:

```
namespace QAServices.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

            return View();
        }

        //[Route("Home/Welcome")] I have also tried this but it doesn't work.
        public HttpResponseMessage Welcome()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            return response;
        }

        public ActionResult ProductPage()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

RouteConfig

```
namespace QAServices
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig

```
namespace QAServices
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { action = "GET", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run my new action I am having following error:

```
<Error>
    <Message>
        No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:1095/Home/Welcome'.
    </Message>
    <MessageDetail>
        No type was found that matches the controller named 'Home'.
    </MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

I have followed these but can't figure out what is wrong:

- [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)
- [Getting Started with ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)
- [Routing Basics in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624180/Routing-Basics-in-ASP-NET-Web-API)
- [Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me. I get the response `StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: , Headers: { }`.

Your `HomeController` is just a regular MVC controller. However, the response you are getting appears to be a WebApi response. So it seems to indicate that the request is being routed to an ApiController.

Is it possible you have an ApiController in your project that is decorated with `[RoutePrefix("Home")]` which has no `Welcome` action method?

Also, if you have a mix of ApiController and MVC Controller, I would leave the default WebApiConfig route template of `api/{controller}/{id}` or at least differentiate if from that used for MVC controller.

Answer (score 0):

Change `public HttpResponseMessage Welcome()` to `public ActionResult Welcome()`.  In ASP.NET MVC controller actions need to return ActionResult.